# SQL query to update 1 column based on another column

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

i have two columns in a table "id_order" & "id_customer"
i want to update the "id_customer" data via importing sql file (as they are around 4000+ lines/or is it possible to do it directly in php my admin?), so the "id_customer" data will be populated against the "id_order"

my sql file data is in this format
first one is "id_order" & second one is "id_customer"

```
(8113, 9002),
(8102, 8969),
(8114, 44),
(8116, 9010),
(8118, 8919),
(8120, 9020),
(3581, 3633),
(3582, 3634),
(3583, 3635),
(3584, 3636),
(3585, 3455),
```

.........
again for clarification the "id_customer" only need to be updated.
your support in this regards will be highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your problem with examples of data, table schema and your queries/code

Comment: The possible answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807528/1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds