# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM

Tags: sql, mariadb

when i run this below query , i get error. what mistake i am doing in it?

`

```
UPDATE
  psu6_orders
SET
  psu6_orders.id_customer = psu6_orders2.id_customer
FROM
  psu6_orders,
  psu6_orders2
WHERE
  psu6_orders.id_order = psu6_orders2.id_order;
`
```

i get this error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
```

psu6_orders,
psu6_orders2
WHERE
psu6_orders.id_order = psu6_or...' at line 5'

Comment: `FROM` is not a valid keyword in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: this is not how you do an update in maria -- you need a corelated sub-query

Comment: ok, please can you correct or guide me further how this statement will be done in mariadb?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/

Answer (score 1):

```
 UPDATE psu6_orders, psu6_orders2 
   SET psu6_orders.id_customer = psu6_orders2.id_customer
   WHERE psu6_orders.id_order = psu6_orders2.id_order;
```

Here is the help page that has this exact code as an example https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/